# Can I hide a whole paragraph using Conditional Text Automation in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, document-automation

I have a MS Word document shared between different projects. Some paragraphs only apply to some specific projects, so I'd like to hide them using custom fields.

I found [this interesting page](https://support.clio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204459577-Tutorial-Using-Conditional-Text-in-Document-Automation) explaing how to insert conditional text. However, this makes it possible to hide a small piece of text, in my case, it's a whole paragraph I'd like to hide, including possible tables, pictures...

I found to way to transform

```
IF "<< Matter.CustomField.Pleading >>" = "guilty" "The defendant pleads "guilty"." "The defendant pleads "not guilty"."
```

into

```
IF "<< Matter.CustomField.Pleading >>" = "guilty" 
"The defendant pleads "guilty"."
including images, tables
ELSE
"The defendant pleads "not guilty"."
including images, tables
ENDIF
```

is it doable (Note that I'd like to avoid using macros, if possible)

Comment: Would the info in [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/1146674/multiple-documents-from-one-source-1-resume-source-that-can-generate-three-or-m/) suit your needs?

Comment: @cnread: It could. Solution A won't as I need to include tables and grpahs. However, Soluiont B could. I tested and I could create tow different "Quick Parts" and then add a control that lets me switch between them. However, I was unable to successfully create a macro that would select all controls and switch to a specific version...could you post a short example/tuto to your other post?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't obvious, but you're able to embed images and charts within the IF field in Word itself! For example:

`IF "[Your Field]" = "guilty" "[text if guilty][image][chart][text]" "[text if not guilty][image][chart][text]"`

That will evaluate [Your Field], and if it equals "guilty" it will display all the text, images, whatever is between the following quotes. If it doesn't equal guilty it'll show whatever text and images is between the final quotes.